# Expection in thread "main" java,lang.ArrayIndexOutOFBoundsExecption

Tags: java, arrays

No Problem while compiling or running but at the end of running the program it just prints out this
`Expection in thread "main" java,lang.ArrayIndexOutOFBoundsExecption`, any guess to why

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ex1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        //dim equals too a.length
        int dim = s.nextInt();
        // value the ammount i wanna add too the array
        int value = s.nextInt();

        int[] a = new int[dim];

        for(int i = 0; i <= a.length ; ++i) {               
            a[i] = value;
            System.out.print(a[i]);
        }       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i <= a.length ; ++i)
```

is the place where the `ArrayOutOfBounds Exception` occurs. This is because array indexes start from 0 and end at length-1(in your case,`dim-1`) not length(`dim`). So change your `for` loop to

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length ; ++i)
```